# LXDE: How to run a program/command when I press one or more keys?

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, lxde

I have a numpad on my keyboard and I want to make the keys do something when (the otherwise useless) <kbd>ScrollLock</kbd> is on under LXDE graphical environment.

For example, I want to run my browser when I press <kbd>7</kbd> and <kbd>ScrollLock</kbd> is on.

Another example is to open the tile manager when I press two or more mouse keys at once.

Comment: This is mostly the realm of your specific window manager or desktop environment (GNOME, KDE, etc).  There isn't a universal method.

Comment: There is a method provided through X though: `xbindkeys` will be window manager and desktop environment independent.

Comment: I'm using LXDE.

Comment: xbindeys-config only works when root

Comment: http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXDE:Questions#Change_hotkeys

Comment: @goldilocks thanks it works! BUT how do i make the keys only work when scroll lock is on? And do You know some GUI program for configuration?

Answer (score 2):

on `~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml` you can add some keybends to make a program to start when you press it.

```
<keybind key="C-A-L">      
  <action name="Execute">        
    <command>xscreensaver-command -lock</command>      
  </action>    
</keybind>
```

Just read what @goldilocks added. :) http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXDE:Questions#Change_hotkeys

Then on a terminal type: `openbox --reconfigure` for changes to take effect.

Comment: yeah me too now I'm just searching for a GUI app because that file is vvveerrryyy lllooonnggg.And I still don't know how to make it work only when scroll lock is on.